# C++ - Template specialization by templated class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I've got a templated class in which I need to specialize few methods for class that is also templated. To be more specific: I try to combine smart array and shared pointer:

```
template <class T>
int sortedArray< smartPtr<T> >::insert(const T& object) {
...
}
```

With this syntax I get following errors:

```
main.cpp:162:55: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class sortedArray<smartPtr<T> >’
int sortedArray< smartPtr<T> >::insert(const T& object) {
                                                      ^
main.cpp:87:7: error: declaration of ‘class sortedArray<smartPtr<T> >’
 class sortedArray {
       ^
```

Is it even possible to do this kind of thing?

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on in your code. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partially specialize the entire class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct sortedArray<smartPtr<T>> {
    void insert(const smartPtr<T>& object) {
        ....
    }

    // everything else
};
```

Or you could *explicitly* specialize a single method:

> An explicit specialization may be declared for a function template, a class template, a member of a class template **or a member template**.

as in:

```
template <>
void sortedArray<smartPtr<int>>::insert(const smartPtr<int>& object) {
    ...
}
```

But you cannot *partially* specialize just a single method.

Comment: Sadly, that seems to be the right answer. So "copy the whole class" it is.